# Shortest way to output the input c++

Tags: c++

A C++ program that can output the input it gets in no more than 55 characters.

Example input:

```
abc
123
bjgf
```

Example output:

```
abc
123
bjgf
```

The shortest code that worked for me so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    int i;
    while((i=std::cin.get())!=EOF)
    {
        std::cout.put(i);
    }
}
```

Will a different header work?

Comment: main() without type is non-iso

Comment: Looks like this might be a better fit for [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). But I am not familiar enough with that site's rules to know whether more work would be needed to make it acceptable there, so please look around before posting.

Answer (score 4):

Any reason not to do the fast version?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << std::cin.rdbuf();
    return 0;
}
```

It is shorter than your version despite being correct C++ and being properly formatted, too.

Comment: @SchulzeThomas: I see that this change was approved but I have deliberately left off the `return 0;` as it is unnecessary and, obviously, makes the code longer. The relevant section of the C++ standard is 3.6.1 [basic.start.main] paragraph 5 last sentence: "... If control reaches the end of `main` without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0;`". The code is still shorter than the original, though.